# How to redirect a user to a site only after successful stripe payment?

Tags: node.js, express, stripe-payments

For my website i have one site to explain the pricing plans and where you can submit your email and credit card info. After that you get redirected to the create account site. I want to redirect though only to the site if payment was successful - otherwise, the /createaccount url shouldn't be accessible. I have some ideas on how to do that but would need help with that or tipps.

In the past I tried to add some id to the /createaccount:id url but that didnt work out.

Frontend code is the typical stripe subscription code with stripe.elemens and elements.create('card')

Backend code looks like that:

```
app.post("/charge", (req, res) => {
let email = req.body.email;
let card = req.body.stripeToken;
let amount = req.body.plan;
let interval = req.body.interval;
const createSubscription = async () => {
const stripe = require("stripe")(SK);
const {
  data: plans
} = await stripe.plans.list({
  product: "prod_id"
})
// Create Customer
const customer = await stripe.customers.create({
  email: email,
  card: card,
});
const planToSubscribeTo = plans.find(p => p.interval === interval)
// Subscribe Customer to plan
const subscription = await stripe.subscriptions.create({
  customer: customer.id,
  items: [{
    plan: planToSubscribeTo.id
  }],
});
return {
  customer,
  // prodgHack,
  planToSubscribeTo,
  // ThreeMonthFreeCoupon,
  subscription
};
};

console.log('Creating subscriptions ...... ');
createSubscription().then((sub) => {
 console.log(sub);
}).catch(err => {
 console.warn('Failed to create subscriptions ', err);
});
res.redirect('/createAccount');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Stripe in the past (though for making a charge and not a subscription), assuming that the process is similar I have done something like below

```
app.post('/payment', async (req, res) => {
  stripe.charges.create({
    amount: 10000,
    currency: 'gbp',
    description: 'Description Here',
    source: req.body.stripeToken,
    receipt_email: req.body.stripeEmail,
    metadata: { email: req.body.stripeEmail },
  }, async (err, charge) => {
    if (err && err.type === 'StripeCardError') {
      res.render('payment_declined');
    } else {
      // Do anything else here like update DB etc and then render view
      res.render('successful_payment');
    }
  });
});
```

Whether this is the correct way or I have missed pieces out I am unsure but maybe this gets you a little further? If not happy to remove this answer for someone else to add something

Also as a side note in your code you probably don't need to declare variables to the following, just call them directly

```
let email = req.body.email;
let card = req.body.stripeToken;
let amount = req.body.plan;
let interval = req.body.interval;
// So just use req.body.email, req.body.plan where required
```

`const stripe = require("stripe")(SK);` is better placed at the top of your file (call it once only, what happens if you have multiple payment paths in your application) as opposed to being in the post function itself